# Should my 'Person' class has an int sex, if I'm following the ISO/IEC 5218?

Tags: java, iso

The ISO/IEC 5218 says the following:

> ISO/IEC 5218 Information technology — Codes for the representation of human sexes is an international standard that defines a representation of human sexes through a language-neutral single-digit code. It can be used in information systems such as database applications. The four codes specified in ISO / IEC 5218 are: 0 = not known, 1 = male, 2 = female, 9 = not applicable.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218).

Taking this into consideration, should I treat the sex as a number? Using this logic, my `Person` constructor would be like that:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int sex;

    public Person(String name, int sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
    }
}
```

I personally believe that having `Person p = new Person("Mike", 1)` is a bit confusing, but I'd like to follow the ISO/IEC in some way. Would this be correct or should I take another approach?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you -- representing sex in this way adds to confusion rather than improving it.  You may want to -- or may need to -- follow ISO/IEC 5218 when you exchange data with another application, data center, microservice, *etc*.;  but I would say that the way you represent it inside your `Person` class is an *implementation detail*.

But if you choose to use ISO/IEC 5218 in this way, you can make the code a lot easier to follow by using one of a few stylistic tricks, for example...

```
public class Person {

    public static final int SEX_MALE = 1;
    public static final int SEX_FEMALE = 2;

    private String name;
    private int sex;

    public Person(String name, int sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
    }
}

Person p = new Person("Mike", Person.SEX_MALE);
```

Comment: Well, if this is an implementation detail, what's the most common in the market? Would `Person` expect a simple `String male` / `String female` or perhaps a `char M` / `char F`, `Person.MALE` / `Person.FEMALE`, or others? I really liked your approach, as I could inspire on it and use for race, for example.

Comment: As far as an industry best practice, I'm confident different (smart) people will give you different answers.  If it were me -- given only what I know about this scenario (which isn't a lot) -- I would lean toward modeling Sex as an enumeration.

Comment: Enum would be a great option, you're not the first to recommend it, some colleagues said the same, I could use it for sex and race. I think I'll go with it then.